# How can I implement pagination buttons using CSS?

Tags: css, datatable, pagination, styles

I am interested in giving style to my datatable pagination buttons because I am having trouble with a template that I bought and paginations buttons are not displaying, I am really tired of this and I decided to implement the style of buttons.

I want this:
[Image](https://i.ibb.co/8swKgpV/image.png)

have a style like this: 
[Image2](https://i.ibb.co/N104WP2/image.png)

Can anyone share me the CSS that a data table uses?

I tried to implement it

```
        .dataTables_paginate a {
            padding: 6px 9px !important;
            background: #54c5e6 !important;
            border-color: #2196F3 !important;
        }
```

but I only got this result: [Image3](https://i.ibb.co/QcBStsR/image.png)

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1109276866689544194/pu/vid/1280x720/2mRktEiGRqz7x40c.mp4?tag=8

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this CSS if someone was wondering:

```
        .pagination {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 0;
            margin: 20px 0;
            border-radius: 4px
        }

            .pagination > li {
                display: inline
            }

                .pagination > li > a,
                .pagination > li > span {
                    position: relative;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 6px 12px;
                    margin-left: -1px;
                    line-height: 1.428571429;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border: 1px solid #ddd
                }

                .pagination > li:first-child > a,
                .pagination > li:first-child > span {
                    margin-left: 0;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
                    border-top-left-radius: 4px
                }

                .pagination > li:last-child > a,
                .pagination > li:last-child > span {
                    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px
                }

                .pagination > li > a:hover,
                .pagination > li > span:hover,
                .pagination > li > a:focus,
                .pagination > li > span:focus {
                    background-color: #eee
                }

            .pagination > .active > a,
            .pagination > .active > span,
            .pagination > .active > a:hover,
            .pagination > .active > span:hover,
            .pagination > .active > a:focus,
            .pagination > .active > span:focus {
                z-index: 2;
                color: #fff;
                cursor: default;
                background-color: #428bca;
                border-color: #428bca
            }

            .pagination > .disabled > span,
            .pagination > .disabled > span:hover,
            .pagination > .disabled > span:focus,
            .pagination > .disabled > a,
            .pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
            .pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
                color: #999;
                cursor: not-allowed;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-color: #ddd
            }

        .pagination-lg > li > a,
        .pagination-lg > li > span {
            padding: 10px 16px;
            font-size: 18px
        }

        .pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
        .pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
            border-top-left-radius: 6px
        }

        .pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
        .pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
            border-top-right-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px
        }

        .pagination-sm > li > a,
        .pagination-sm > li > span {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            font-size: 12px
        }

        .pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
        .pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
            border-top-left-radius: 3px
        }

        .pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
        .pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
            border-top-right-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 3px
        }


        div.dataTables_paginate {
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
        }

            div.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
                margin: 2px;
            }
```